# C++ while loop with 2 conditions, VS. for loop with 2 conditions?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, coding-style

If I wanted to iterate through a string, and stop once I found either the letter "o" or the end of the string, would it make any difference to use a while loop to check the 2 conditions, or a for loop with 2 conditions?

```
const int STRING_SIZE = 16;
char str[STRING_SIZE] = "a bunch of words";
```

for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < STRING_SIZE && str[i] != 'o'; i++){
    //do something
}
```

while loop

```
int i = 0;

while (i < STRING_SIZE && str[i] != 'o'){
    //do something
    i++
}
```

Is there a performance difference between the two? Is one better practice than the other?

Comment: No, there will not be any performance advantage

Comment: There is no performance difference, but the loops are semantically different, and will yield different results.

Comment: I think the `while` loop is slightly preferable, because it is the convention for loops that will continue for an unknown number of iterations, while `for` loops are for cases where the number of iterations is (or can be) known beforehand. It's a matter of style, not performance.

Comment: There is only a difference between the loops: `for` is like `while(consdition)` is eavaluated first then if succeeded executes. `do-while`  is at least executed at least once whatever the condition maybe.

Comment: I don't know why I used a do-while loop in the example (changed) but ignoring that, would one be preferred over the other?

Comment: Have you tried compiling both examples?  Most compilers will produce the same machine code for both (and also for the equivalent `for` loop with early `break`, if optimising), answering one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in performance between the two loops except that:

`for()` Checks condition then if true its body is executed. So `for` is simile to `while` loop.

`do-while` loop works a slightly different: It executes then checks so at least an execution is ensured.